# Analog SetOnTouchListener or how it use in xamarin, what argument must be

Tags: android, xamarin, ontouchlistener

I need use SetOnTouchListener:

```
LinearLayout cardLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Layout.CardList);
cardLinearLayout.SetOnTouchListener (this);//Can't use THIS, must be argument  with IOnTouchListener type. Where can I get this argument?
```

[image]

I want use it for ViewFlipper. Maybe other way exists.

Comment: make sure you are implementing [View.IOnTouchListener](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch) in Activity ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK But I don't have Activity for CardList, only MainActivity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android a lot of the `Listener` interfaces have been converted to `events` for more of a C# type of code.

So on all `View`s there is a `Touch` event which corresponds to the stuff happening in the `OnTouchListener`.

However, if you really, really want to, you can implement the `IOnTouchListener` interface like so:

```
public class MyOnTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

And then use it on your `LinearLayout` like so:

```
cardLinearLayout.SetOnTouchListener (new MyOnTouchListener());
```

You can compare that to the `Touch` event, which only takes one line of code:

```
cardLinearLayout.Touch += (s, e) => { /* do stuff */ };
```

Comment: Just to clarify, OnTouch has return value of bool. Where does this bool go when one is using event handler?

Comment: There is a `Handled` property on the second, `e`, argument.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron, I try to use the last form, but when I add the Touch The slider stop to work. Look the code:

var thisButton = Control as Android.Widget.SeekBar;

            thisButton.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs args) =>
            {
                switch (args.Event.Action)
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        customButton.OnReleased();
                        break;
                }
            };

Comment: @BrunoCosta as mentioned in the comment above, you need to use the `e.Handled` property and set it to either true or false, depending on the behavior you want.